# Windows service can access userdir from Go .exe but not from C .exe

Tags: c, windows, go

I have a Windows service running under the local system account. It is written in Go and uses exec.Command() to execute 2 .exes, one written in Go, the other in C. They both need to access a directory in C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\sandbox\ , the Golang one can access it, the C one can not.

The directory exists before and after the attempted access.

So:

myservice.exe(written in Go):

```
    exec.Command("go_access_dir.exe") //<- can access C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\sandbox\
    exec.Command("c_access_dir.exe") //<- can not access C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\sandbox\
```

go_access_dir.go:

```
    // create file
    f, err := os.Create("go-main.log")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // remember to close the file
    defer f.Close()

fmt.Println("-- begin main")

   currentUser, err__ := user.Current()
   if err__ != nil {
      //log.Fatalf(err__.Error())
   }

   homedir := currentUser.HomeDir

   sandbox_dir := homedir + sandboxDir

        _, err = f.WriteString("sandbox_dir ="+sandbox_dir + "\n")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

    file, err := os.Open(sandbox_dir)
    if err != nil {
//      log.Fatalf("failed opening directory: %s", err)

        _, err = f.WriteString("failed opening directory ="+sandbox_dir + " error "+ err.Error()+"\n")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

    }
    defer file.Close()

    list,_ := file.Readdirnames(0) // 0 to read all files and folders
    for _, name := range list {
        fmt.Println(name)
            _, err = f.WriteString(name + "\n")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

    }

  
}
```

This prints the directory contents showing expected functionality:

```
sandbox_dir =C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\sandbox\
folder1
folder2
test1.doc
test10.doc
```

c_access_dir.c:

```
FILE *fdout = fopen("list_dir.log","w");


    DIR* directory = NULL;
    if ((directory = opendir(dir_name)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(fdout, "Can't open |%s|\n", dir_name);
        fprintf(fdout, "error: %s\n",  strerror(errno));
        return;
    }else{
        fprintf(fdout, "|%s| opens fine\n", dir_name);

        DIR *dp;
        struct dirent *ep;

        dp = opendir (dir_name);
        if (dp != NULL)
        {
            while (ep = readdir (dp)){
                fprintf(fdout, "|%s| \n", ep->d_name);
            }
            (void) closedir (dp);
        }
    }
  
fclose(fdout);
```

This prints:

```
Can't open |C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\sandbox\|
error: No such file or directory
```

"C:\Windows\Temp\sandbox\" works in the opendir call though.

Trying with FindFirstFile:

```
    HANDLE fileHandle;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    LARGE_INTEGER szDir;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fileData;
DWORD dwError=0;

char *this_file_name = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\sandbox\\*";//"C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/sandbox/*"; does the same thing.

fprintf(fdout, "1193 working with this_file_name %s \n", this_file_name);
fprintf(fdout, "findfirstfile\n");
    fileHandle = FindFirstFileA(this_file_name, &FindFileData);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == fileHandle) {
        fprintf(fdout, "Invalid File Handle Value \n");
        dwError = GetLastError();
        fprintf(fdout, "FindFirstFile error  %d\n",dwError);
    }
    do
    {
        fprintf(fdout, "%s\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
    } while (FindNextFile(fileHandle, &FindFileData) != 0);
```

will print the directories only, no files(there are files in the root dir and in folder1, which are accessible via a Go executable if I shell out immediately before and after the above FindFirstFile snippet:

```
.
..
folder1
```

Comment: If `opendir` fails, call `perror` to find out *why* it fails.  Also, you should really be using `FindFirstFile` or `_findfirst` on Windows.

Comment: good point. I added the error code -- The C exe thinks the dir does not exist, but it exists before and after the service execution and is accessible if I run the Go .exe before and after the C .exe.

Comment: Not sure how you're using `opendir` on windows (mingw perhaps), but I'm guessing it's expecting forward slashes for directory separators instead of backslashes.  If you use `FindFirstFile` you shouldn't have that problem.

Comment: @dbush, I support your idea. I'd not use C's libc functions for pure-Windows program, if possible.

Comment: A minor nitpick: you should either immediately save `errno` after the error or just immediately use it (say, by calling `perror`). In your code, if the first `fprintf` fails to whatever reason, it will rewrite the `errno`.

Comment: >Not sure how you're using opendir on windows (mingw perhaps)
Yeah, mingw. 

Trying with FindFirstFile doesn't itself solve it either:

``
    HANDLE fileHandle;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    LARGE_INTEGER szDir;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fileData;
    fileHandle = FindFirstFile(dir_name, &ffd);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == fileHandle)
        printf("Invalid File Handle Value \n");

    do
    {
fprintf(fdout, "%s\n", ffd.cFileName);
    } while (FindNextFile(fileHandle, &ffd) != 0);
````
outputs "Invalid File Handle Value "

Comment: Also, passing the directory as "C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/sandbox/" has the same error

Comment: Does `/C/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/sandbox/` work? What if you remove the trailing slash in all the cases?

Comment: Call `GetLastError()` after getting an error from `FindFirstFile`, and then `FormatMessage` it (with `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM`). Basically we're trying to figure out "true" error from the system. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/listing-the-files-in-a-directory) for a complete example.

Comment: /C/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/sandbox/  doesn't work. Trying to get GetLastError() going.

FWIW, in the original opendir code above, "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\sandbox\\" works.

Comment: >What if you remove the trailing slash in all the cases?

This doesn't appear to help. :(

Comment: Pairs of double slashes are there to produce single backslashes in C string literals. The actual function calls sees single backslashes.

Comment: GetLastError() returns 6 after FindFirstFile("C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\sandbox\\" FWIW.

Trying to figure out FormatMessage(FormatMessageA?) to decode this.

ack on the \\ escaping to \

Comment: 6 is `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` :-\

Comment: BTW did you carefully read the section "Parameters" of the [FindFirstFile docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea)?

Comment: Thanks. I think I have read the fine print. Is there something I am missing?



char *this_file_name = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\sandbox";//I've also tried ending in \\ all /'s and /C/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/sandbox/

        fprintf(fdout, "this_file_name %s \n", this_file_name);

    fileHandle = FindFirstFileA(this_file_name, &ffd); 

Error is always 6 == ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Comment: «Is there something I am missing?»–I think yes, as I read the manual, the function expects a so-called [glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), not just a bare directory pathname.

Comment: Thanks Kostik.

I think I am trying that a couple of ways. I added a snippet of what I am trying with FindFirstFile above.

If I end in \\*, it prints the directories, but not the files. If I end in *.doc, it errors with "Invalid File Handle Value ".

Comment: I have no idea what's happening on your part. [This code](https://gist.github.com/kostix/3c7ac9c1679c71787a272b8eed3a722b) works for me (compiled using MinGW cross-compiler of GCC 12 on Debian, and tested under Wine). I mean, it correctly handles all the cases I can think of, and prints directories as well as files. Just in case, notice that Unicode console output on Windows is notoriously quirky; in particular, I had to change `""` to `"Russian"` in the call to `setlocale` in order to get non-English file and firectory names printed, so YMMV. BTW this might be the case of missing names.

Comment: …and maybe it will work just OK for you if you use the `FooA` legacy Win32 API calls combined with non-Unicode-aware stdlib I/O functions such as `fputs`. I mean, there's a field for experimenting.

Comment: JFTR, my code example from the gist was compiled using `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 -municode -Wall -o find_first_file.exe find_first_file.c`